# any border blank space trick ? for CSS

Tags: border, css

I need some trick to insert border blank space by using CSS like this..

[image: any border blank space trick ? for CSS]

I using CSS box-shadow like this

```
 box-shadow:
        -1px 0px 0px 0px #000,
        0px -1px 0px 0px #000,
        0px 1px 0px 0px #000,
        1px 1px 0px 0px #000
```

I have no idea how to make border / shadow look like the picture.

I will use only one html element..  `<div></div>`

Any trick ?

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/ES66k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
div {
  width:300px;
  height:170px;
  margin:100px;
  position:relative;

 background:#ccc;

}

div:before, div:after {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
div:before {
    width:280px; /*****-20px*****/
    height:168px; /*****-2px*****/

    margin-left:10px;
    border-top:1px solid #f00;
    border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
}
div:after {
    width:298px; /*****-2px*****/
    height:150px; /*****-20px*****/

    margin-top:10px;
    border-left:1px solid #f00;
    border-right:1px solid #f00;
}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/ES66k/4/

Done now, Don't need to set background-color :D

But thanks @Fabrizio Calderan anyway :D

Answer (score 3):

with one div only: http://jsfiddle.net/ES66k/1/ (tested on Fx18 and chrome)

```
div {
  width:300px;
  height:170px;
  margin:100px;
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  position: relative;
}

div:after, div:before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: -1px;
   width: 20px;
   height: 172px;
   border-top: 40px white solid;
   border-bottom: 40px white solid;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:before { border-left: 1px black solid; left: 0; }
div:after { border-right: 1px black solid; right: 0; }
```

It's bit hacky, anyway, since it's relying on a fixed height and on a solid color as background (white) but maybe could be useful for your purpose.

Comment: Yes thanks :D , But we have to set height & width in `div:after, div:before {}` ?

Comment: I have a idea now , I dont want to set background-color , http://jsfiddle.net/ES66k/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can create 4 `<div>`'s with classes `.top-left`, `.top-right`, `.bottom-left` and `.bottom-right`. Make them absolute and the container relative. Size them, make them the color of the containers bg-color and get them to the corners with `top, right, bottom and left` properties. Their value must be **minus** the **border width**.
Here is example of element with 3px border:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="corner top-left"></div>
    <div class="corner top-right"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom-left"></div>
    <div class="corner bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #666;
    position:relative; 
}

.corner{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff; 
    position: absolute;
}

.top-left{
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
}
.top-right {
    top: -3px;
    right: -3px;
}
.bottom-left{
    bottom: -3px;
    left: -3px;
}
.bottom-right{
    bottom: -3px;
    right: -3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the CSS3 attribute border-image:

Here's a demo you can have a look and try out yourself: [**CSS3 border-image**](http://www.norabrowndesign.com/css-experiments/border-image-anim.html)

Comment: I think CSS3 border-image is a bad thing in CSS3 (for me) :(